# Excel - format multiple values in cell

Tags: excel, format, string-formatting

I have a tricky issue in excel; I have a concatenated string, consiting of two time-values:

Time values in Formatted Cells = 15:00:00 and 23:00:00

Concatenated Cell SHOULD be 15:00:00 23:00:00

Concatenated Cell Currently is 0.625 0.95833...

I understand the problem Excel has with multiple values in one cell - but is there any way to format both of them in one cell?

As those numbers come from a calculation in the first place, I can't really re-format them.

Cheers
Michael

---

Proposed solution results in this, I can't figure out why? (Excel 16 on Windows)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula entered in cell `D1`.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")&" "&TEXT(B1,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

[image]

Comment: Are we using a different version of Excel? I get a stupid prompt... I'll add it to my question

Comment: try replacing coma(,) with semicolumn(;) in formula

Comment: Working perfectly fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this format,
A1 cell contains 15:00:00 and B1 cell contains 23:00:00

```
=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")&" " &TEXT(B1,"hh:mm:ss")
```